# passing variables through input tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want authenticated admin users to be able to enter variables for substitution in a web form. Entering "email`<<eric>>` or `<<jeremy>>`" would replace `<<eric>>` and `<<jeremy>>` with the contents of the variables eric and jeremy.

```
eric = "<a href='mailto:eric.roberts@example.com'>Eric Roberts</a>"
jeremy = "<a href='mailto:jeremy.smith@example.com'>Jeremy Smith</a>"
blurb = params[:my_input].gsub(/<<(\w+)>>/, "\#{\1}")
```

did not work nor did using $1 or eval. The output is to be redisplayed on the web site. The delimiters are unimportant as long as the admins can use these shortcut variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps it is easier to store your replacement strings in a hash with the key being the name of the replacement string. Ie:

```
substitutions = {
  'eric' => "<a href='mailto:eric.roberts@example.com'>Eric Roberts</a>",
  'jeremy' => "<a href='mailto:jeremy.smith@example.com'>Jeremy Smith</a>"
}

match = params[:my_input].match(/<<(\w+)>>/)
blurb = substitutions[match[1]] if match
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked in a loop, and gave me a substitution list to display.